# How to keep column headers with attribute table join

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I successfully joined an attribute table to a shapefile using the method below.

[image]

But the new attribute table does not include the original column headers from the joined table. They've been replaced with something generic. See below.

[image]

Is there a way to keep the original column headers from the table that was joined?

Comment: I think this is related to the long name of the joined layer. Rename it to something shorter and retry the join.

Comment: can't reproduce this behavior  even though I use a very long name for the layer and also a custom prefix (Qgis 2.18.11 ). Please give more detail on your model, qgis version, share samples of your files  etc.